# Como instaciar um Form em outro Form Com Parâmeto C#

Tags: c#

OpenChildForm(new FormListaPesagens());

Aqui em baixo Chamo Um form e Passo Uma variável Para ele

```
FormNotaPesagem fp;
        Form1 fc;

        

        public FormListaPesagens( FormNotaPesagem f, Form1 c)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            geraGrade();

            fp = f;
            fc = c;
            
        }
```

Aqui Chamo o Form que Passei a variavel ele Abre Normal-mente

```
FormListaPesagens formListaPesagens = new FormListaPesagens(this);
```

mas quando Chamo o mesmo Form em Outro ele Nao Abre pede (parameto) ja Coloque (this da erro, f que e a variavel da erro Vcs Pode Me Ajudar);

OpenChildForm(new FormListaPesagens(<=***

### texto em negrito

*****preciso passar Algo Aqui=>));**

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! 

Para melhorar sua experiência aqui, fazer a pergunta de forma que possa ser respondida, recomendo ler: [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Primeiramente o operador "new" serve para criar uma nova instância de uma classe, e o trecho de código que você compartilhou tem apenas a definição de um método.

Para invocarmos um método de dentro da mesma classe que ele está sendo definido, basta atender a assinatura do método.

Eu não sei a definição dos construtores dos parâmetros mas ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
FormListaPesagens( new FormNotaPesagem(), new Form1() );
```

Para invocar de algum outro lugar você deve ou torná-lo estático:

```
// Na assinatura do método:
public static FormListaPesagens( FormNotaPesagem f, Form1 c) 
{ }

// Onde ele é invocado 
NomeDaClasse.FormListaPesagens( new FormNotaPesagem(), new Form1() );
```

ou criar antes uma instância da classe que o define:

```
var instancia = new NomeDaClasse();
instancia.FormListaPesagens( new FormNotaPesagem(), new Form1() );
```